# Can blender be used to analysis the acoustics of a 3D designed room or hall?

Tags: modeling, audio

Blender supports ray-tracing for the visuals. Can this feature be used to support audio-wave propagation, delay and frequency response in a 3D designed room?

--HPS

Comment: imho that's not possible out of the box, and it could not be really a blender feature, since blender's main scope is another one (a tool for visual artists to produce images and animations), but perhaps you are asking if it could be modified (forked) to support audio waves instead of light waves?

Comment: I've wondered this before as well. There is no functionality like that built in, but I don't see why it couldn't be added with an add-on. It would probably be a non-trivial add-on, very specialized and able to crunch some serious calculations. But impossible? No, I don't think it's impossible. In fact, I think you're describing a render engine for audio / acoustics.

Comment: I wonder if sound waves propagate and reflect in a similar fashion to light and photons. Could one lamp be used to simulate a sound source, use color to simulate frequency, and model material properties to make stuff glossiness and transparency represent sound absorption and scattering? Caustics  would be the equivalent of reverberation?

Comment: I thing this is probably related to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81485/how-to-calculate-for-every-ray-the-total-distance-it-has-traveled-from-camera-to as the total ray length would affect its phase and therefore how it would interfere.

Answer (score 1):

E.A.R seems to be pretty much what you looking for
although it hasn't been updated for quite long
https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?252708-E-A-R-Evaluation-of-Acoustics-using-Ray-tracing
http://www.explauralisation.org/